# Security by Obscurity on phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, security, phpmyadmin

So I have about 5-6 people who need access to phpMyAdmin on a daily basis, (CEO,CTO etc) and they all want access outside of their office. Currently I am adding and removing Ip address to fix this issue and they do not want to use a vpn. So! I was wondering if to prevent bots from getting access to phpMyAdmin I could setup a custom url with a 32 character hash something like

www.mydomain.com/d65g4d6f5gdg65d15aw4urtb5

That would bring up phpMyAdmin which would make it hard to find in the first place, then do the same thing for username and password, really big hash for user and password. Then just change the config to allow access from all ip address. Is this secure enough? Thanks for any input.

Comment: is this over https?  If they are entering their credentials it should be.  In my opinion, phpMyAdmin is for the developer, and you should build interfaces for the users.  I guess if their privileges are limited its alright.

Comment: phpMyAdmin should be avoided at all costs in a live environment. Security through obscurity isn't *really* security at all (though as @RightClick mentions, https will help a *lot* here). If possible I'd set them up with something like [MySql Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) (other alternatives exist) and give them SSH keys instead.

Answer (score -2):

The most problematic part can be the fact that randomly new phpMyAdmin exploits are discovered, so it's better if people do not know you have it... First of all you should stop benign and neutral search engines' crawlers via your *robots.txt*, but I believe you already took that step.
Personally, I believe a very strong password is unbreakable for every attacker who can't count on a cluster of computers, as long as the hashing algorithm is decent. But if you put something like `My P@s5w0OrD mU57 B3 ExXxtr3m3lY H@rd 70 Cr4sh!i!`, then the only ones you should fear are the NSA and few others, even under MD5 encryption ;) 
Of course, provided that you have SSL/TLS enabled, which will (try to) prevent people from snooping into your web sessions...

Comment: MD5 encryption is broken because you don't need to find the original password, anything that hashes to the same value is fine. It's got nothing to do with password length. Additionally, don't use SSL any more. If your server doesn't support TLS, scrap it. If your users don't support TLS scrap them. Finally, although good robots will abide robots.txt, evil ones will use it to find the goods.

Comment: **hashing != encryption**

Comment: Guys, this was just to say that a complex password with a good hashing algorithm (as for example sha512) will solve most of the problems, being almost unbreakable. And for the part of crawlers, it's better if people have to dig to find the correct link than if they can just google for it. And putting the interesting directory farther in the tree (`www.mysite.com/dir1/phpmyadmin`) disallowing the crawling of `dir1` will do what's necessary to obfuscate the link. Then well, good encryption will do the rest. Why avoiding SSL/TLS, in your opinion?